# How do I increase the amount of space between the section number and title in a ToC?

Tags: spacing, table-of-contents

I just cannot figure out how to widen this space in a LaTeX table of contents:
[image]

MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\renewcommand{\thesection}{\Roman{section}}
\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\arabic{subsection}}

\title{MWE}
\author{John Doe}
\date{August 2022}

\begin{document}
    \maketitle
    As you can clearly see, the "III" is far too close the the title name.
    \tableofcontents
    \clearpage
    \section{Test}
    \section{Test}
    \section{Test}
    \section{Test}
    \section{Test}
\end{document}
```

I've already tried the "similar questions" to no avail.
Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Can you show us a short compilable TeX code resulting in your issue? Then we do not have to guess what you are doing ...

Comment: Minimal working example added.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the package `tocloft` and change the space allocated to the section numbers in the ToC using `\setlength{\cftsecnumwidth}{<space>}`. It is best to use a font dependent unit like `em` or `ex`.

[image: a]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{tocloft}% to configure the ToC <<<<<
\setlength{\cftsecnumwidth}{4.5ex}% set the width to the section number in the ToC <<<<<

\renewcommand{\thesection}{\Roman{section}}
\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\arabic{subsection}}

\title{MWE}
\author{John Doe}
\date{August 2022}

\begin{document}
    \maketitle
    As you can clearly see, the "III" is far too close the the title name. (not anymore)
    \tableofcontents
    \clearpage
    \section{Test}
    \section{Test}
    \section{Test}
    \section{Test}
    \section{Test}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This works fantastically. Thank you so much!